# session sharing between users in django

Tags: php, django, session, web

Is it possible to share a session between two users in django ? 
Is it possible to do in any other web frameworks (even those in php or ruby etc), or is it something that should never be done, and if I'm thinking of a solution using those, I should come up with a better method ?
I was thinking of making a simple multiplayer tic-tac-to game game for the web, I realize that it can be done nicely using websockets, but for arguments sake, if I could have both users in the same 'game' session in django, I could still have them play. I don't really need an external storage, since I just need to store 9 moves at most (in a matrix like data structure), front end will be updated by ajax.

Comment: If two users will share session, they will share every information that is stored in session, including user account they are logged into. So it's not good solution and sessions are not for it. Consier making simple communication using redis.

Comment: what if its an anonymous session ? There's just player names and moves to be stored ? Is it possible ? whether its a good design idea is a secondary question..

Comment: You still won't be able to distinguish each player.

Comment: a session variable can hold whose turn it is..? I'm sorry I haven't really thought it through very well, since I decided this pet project to learn new things I haven't used before, just this morning, so any Ideas and criticisms are more than welcome, thanks

Comment: You can just add a variable to `settings.py` to hold the game information for all the players (like a fake application scope). Not a scalable method but it should work for a few players.

Comment: I'm not sure that I like that solution. Can someone highlight all  possible techniques two users can communicate using ? (I can only think of users accessing some from of external storage)

Comment: I'm not sure that I like that solution. Can someone highlight all  possible techniques two users can communicate using ? (I can only think of users accessing some from of external storage). I would like to understand your `settings.py` hack too, I don't think I understand how that will work. I'm new at Django.